# How to mark a question as favorite?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

Is there a way to mark a question as favorite?

It would be really great to have a "Your Favorites" dropdown on the nav bar or something like that.

I know I could use bookmarks but there are just too many answers I keep coming back for reference that they simply get lost on my bookmarks.

Comment: see that star? click it.  there is a favorites tab in your profile where they show up

Comment: they are public, so others can see what you like as well, if that matters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is the star next to every question:

[image: Favorite button]

Clicking this adds the question to your list of favorite questions, which can be found on your [profile page](//stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites).

The number next to the menu bar indicates the number of "favorited" questions that have been updated in some way (be it editing, new answers, etc.) since you last checked that tab.

[image: Favorites tab]

When you click on the tab, questions that have been updated will have a yellow background:

[image: Updated questions]