# A single question leads to an Oops! Something bad happened, but only for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, error-message

I was searching on Meta for posts about [favorite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=favorite) and I found a post that seemed interesting: [How to mark a question as favorite?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274918/how-to-mark-a-question-as-favorite)

I clicked the link and was greeted with the error page. I checked with a [few](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6236587#6236587) other [members](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38454707#38454707) who experienced no issue at all. Testing in incognito mode rendered the question without problems.

Here is a GIF of what I see when logged in:

[image]

This only happens with that particular question AFAIK. I'm using Chrome / Windows 10 and verified on Edge. No relevant userscripts running and no errors in the Developer Console. These are the response headers I got:

> ```
> location:/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/274918/how-to-mark-a-question-as-favorite
> status:302 
> strict-transport-security:max-age=15552000 
> vary:Fastly-SSL
> via:1.1 varnish 
> x-cache:MISS 
> x-cache-hits:0 
> x-dns-prefetch-control:off
> x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
> x-request-guid:7bfe195c-4cdd-4d1f-9724-24a9f7c1f55b
> x-served-by:cache-ams4450-AMS 
> x-timer:S1501673062.226659,VS0,VE108
> ```

This still happens 2 months later so I doubt it is a stale cache and I can access that question when I use incognito mode so it is not an issue local to my network. Something in my user profile upsets that post.

What did I do to upset that question and how can I make up with that question?

Comment: The answer posted to that question has an image with non-freehand red circles. Sure you don't have a userscript to block those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not a very common scenario, but here's what happened:

You have a gold badge in [support](/questions/tagged/support). That makes you eligible to edit the dupe targets on that question. The check we run is shared with the check done to see if you're eligible to close that question as a duplicate if it were open.

Where this gets fun is that you can only close as a duplicate with a gold tag badge if you weren't the person who added the tag to the question. So the shared check looks for that as well. Turns out, on the specific question you couldn't access, the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag was added by a user who has since been deleted. Which brought us to a null reference exception and an error page for you.

The fix is live in production now.

Comment: Edge cases FTW...?